# CSS HTML , how to centre a slideshow

Tags: html, css

Hey guys I want to centre my slide show for my website if anyone can help it will be greatly appreciated.

**PROBLEM**
I want to centre the logo and the whole slide show as you can see its a bit to the right
[PROBLEM(IMG)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wD7oL.png)

**CODE**

```css
body {
    background: #E9E9E9;
}
div.box {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    z-index: 5
}


#navMenu {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#navMenu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 30px;
}
#navMenu li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    background: #999;
}

#navMenu > ul > li {
    float: left;
    width: 12.5%;
    /* Set width here (100 / 8 items) */
}
#navMenu ul li a {
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    height: 30px;

    display: block;
    color: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
}
#navMenu ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    visibility: hidden;
    bottom: 100%;
}
#navMenu ul li:hover ul {
    visibility: visible;
}


#navMenu li:hover {
    background: #09F;
}
#navMenu ul li:hover ul li a:hover {
    background: #CCC;
    color: #000;
}
#navMenu a:hover {
    color: #000;
}
.clearFloat {
    clear: both;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
h3 {
    color: #e1c184 text-align: center;
}
/**********end drop down menu*********/
/**********Start slideshow************/

.slideshow {
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.slideshow .css-img {
   width: 90%
   height:90%;
   max-width:90%  
   max-height:90%;
   position: absolute;
   opacity: 0;
   -webkit-animation-name: css-animation-fade;
   -webkit-animation-duration:30s;
   -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
}

 .slideshow .css-img:nth-child(2) {
   -webkit-animation-delay:5s;
 }

  .slideshow .css-img:nth-child(3) {
   -webkit-animation-delay:10s;
 }

  .slideshow .css-img:nth-child(4) {
   -webkit-animation-delay:15s;
 }

  .slideshow .css-img:nth-child(5) {
   -webkit-animation-delay:20s;
 }

  .slideshow .css-img:nth-child(6) {
   -webkit-animation-delay:25s;
 }

@-webkit-keyframes css-animation-fade {
    from { opacity:0;}
    5% {opacity:1;}
    15% {opacity:1;}
    20% {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity: 0;}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Paid Templates Packages</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="paid.css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">
   <link href="paid.css" rel="stlesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="box">
<a href="index.html"><img src="icon1.png" width="50%" height="50%"></a>

 <div id="wrapper">
 <div id="navMenu">

 <ul>
 <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
 <ul>



 </ul> <!-- end inner UL-->


    </li> <!-- end main LI -->
 </ul><!-- end main UL -->

  <ul>
 <li><a href="about.html">About Me</a>
 <ul>
 <li><a href="game.html">Games</a></li> 
 <li><a href="info.html">Information</a></li> 



 </ul> <!-- end inner UL-->


    </li> <!-- end main LI -->
 </ul><!-- end main UL -->

  <ul>
 <li><a href="sm.html">Social Media</a>
 <ul>
 
   


 </ul> <!-- end inner UL-->


    </li> <!-- end main LI -->
 </ul><!-- end main UL -->

  <ul>
 <li><a href="p.html">Packages</a>
 <ul>
  <li><a href="custom(p).html">Custom Work</a></li> 
 <li><a href="download(p).html">Download</a></li> 
 <li><a href="template(p).html">Templates</a></li> 
   <li><a href="paid(p).html">Paid Templates</a></li> 




 </ul> <!-- end inner UL-->


    </li> <!-- end main LI -->
 </ul><!-- end main UL -->

  <ul>
 <li><a href="gd.html">Graphic Design</a>
 <ul>
 <li><a href="custom(gd).html">Custom Work</a></li> 
 <li><a href="download(gd).html">Download</a></li> 
 <li><a href="template(gd).html">Templates</a></li> 
   <li><a href="paid(gd).html">Paid Templates</a></li> 


 </ul> <!-- end inner UL-->


    </li> <!-- end main LI -->
 </ul><!-- end main UL -->

  <ul>
 <li><a href="wd.html">Web Design</a>
 <ul>
 <li><a href="custom(wd).html">Custom Work</a></li> 
 <li><a href="download(wd).html">Download</a></li> 
 <li><a href="template(wd).html">Templates</a></li> 
   <li><a href="paid(wd).html">Paid Templates</a></li> 
 


 </ul> <!-- end inner UL-->


    </li> <!-- end main LI -->
 </ul><!-- end main UL -->

  <ul>
 <li><a href="products.html">Products</a>
 <ul>
 <li><a href="shop.html">Shop</a></li> 
 <li><a href="cart.html">My Cart</a></li> 



 </ul> <!-- end inner UL-->


    </li> <!-- end main LI -->
 </ul><!-- end main UL -->

  <ul>
 <li><a href="cm.html">Contact Me</a>
 <ul>



 </ul> <!-- end inner UL-->


    </li> <!-- end main LI -->
 </ul><!-- end main UL -->

 <br class="clearFloat">

 </div> <!--end navMenu -->
 </div> <!--end wrapper div -->

  <div class="slideshow">
  <img src="icon1.png" class="css-img">
  <img src="icon1.png" class="css-img">
  <img src="icon1.png" class="css-img">
  <img src="icon1.png" class="css-img">
  <img src="icon1.png" class="css-img">
  <img src="icon1.png" class="css-img">
  </div>
  </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

when i try to load my website on chrome the slideshow goes a bit of to the right, if anyone can help it will be greatly appreaciated , thanks in advance 
Kind regards
Zefrolity

In the "RUN SNIPPET" it shows them how I want but when they fade away the second image fades in under the first one and so on

Comment: Can you provide a link to the website?

Comment: i meant i loaded it on chrome its not a proper website yet

Comment: in `.slideshow .css-img` css class replace `position:absolute;' to 'position: relative;'

Comment: @amit that does work but all of the picture in the slideshow dont go into the same spot so if you want to see the whole slideshow i have to scroll down

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. It works for me when I'm center things

```
.slideshow {
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: it still didn't centre the slideshow thanks for your help :D